# Protractor tests randomly stopping on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor, cucumberjs, e2e-testing

I have some e2e tests set up with Protractor and CucumberJS, but and struggling a lot with Chrome. The tests pass fine on Firefox but in Chrome they randomly stop in any step. Some times it just hangs up loading and url, other times sending keys it suddenly stops, other times it hangs up trying to "click" a button. Does any one have any idea? Everything works fine on Firefox. 
I've tried a lot of things: ignoreSyncronization, waitForAngular withoud any luck...
This is my steps definition:

```
module.exports = function() {
var login = new Login();

this.Given('I go on "$url"', function(url, callback) {
    browser.get(url);
    callback();
});

this.Given('I logged in with user "$userName" and password "$password"', function(userName, password, callback) {
    browser.element(by.id('userName')).sendKeys(userName).then(function() {
        browser.element(by.id('password')).sendKeys(password).then(function() {
            browser.element(by.id('btnLogin')).click().then(callback);
        });
    });
});

this.Then('The user is redirected to the Dashboard page on "$dashboardUrl"', function(dashboardUrl, callback) {
    this.expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(dashboardUrl).and.notify(callback);
});

this.Then('I log the user out', function(callback) {
    login.getUserProfileMenuElement().click().then(function() {
        login.getLogUserOutElement().click();
        callback();
    });
});
```

};

Here two different screenshot where it stopped, first time, stopped loading the url, second time, sending keys:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1437542/run1.jpg
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1437542/run2.jpg